# Python multiprocessing: Share data from dynamically created module on windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I'd like to send data defined in a module that was dynamically loaded with imp via a Manager().Queue() on Windows. Is this possible? Here is a minimal testcase to demonstrate what I mean:

```
import imp
import sys
from multiprocessing import Manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = """
def payload():
    print("It works!")
"""

    mod = imp.new_module('testcase')
    exec s in mod.__dict__
    sys.modules['testcase'] = mod

    payload = mod.payload
    payload()  # It works!

    m = Manager()
    queue = m.Queue()
    queue.put(payload)  # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'payload'
```

Note: The use of imp.new_module + exec is just to get the testcase in a single file. The same AttributeError is raised when using imp.load_source.

Note2: This testcase leaves out all the Pool/worker code as the error happens before then.

Here is the output with full traceback from running the above script:

```
It works!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcase.py", line 23, in <module>
    queue.put(payload)  # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'payload'
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\dev\python\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 774, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\dev\python\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 240, in serve_client
    request = recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'payload'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have a "testcase.py" or "testcase.pyc" somewhere on `sys.path`, else this example would raise an `ImportError`. It works on Unix systems that implement `fork`, which allows the current `sys.modules` to be inherited. But on Windows the `payload` function has to be pickled and sent to each child process. This requires an importable module named "testcase", since pickling a function just marshals the module name and function name (e.g.`'ctestcase\npayload\np0\n.'`).